# Are paths in content.opf URL-encoded by standard?

Tags: standards, epub

When processing **EPUB** files, I've ran into the issue that in some epub books the **paths of the xhtml files** are written into the **content.opf URL encoded**.
For example the path "abcá.xhtml" is written into the content.opf as `href="abc%C3%A1.xhtml"` (%C3%A1 being the url encoded representation of the character 'á').

I could not find any information about this anywhere. Is this in the EPUB standard? The EPUB file in question was generated with Adobe InDesign.

UPDATE: I tested the epub with the **Calibre E-book viewer**, with the following results:

- Special character in file name, URL-encoded path in content.opf (abcá.xhtml and `href="abc%C3%A1.xhtml"`): Calibre opens the epub with no problem.
- Special character in file name, special character is directly written into path in content.opf with UTF-8 (abcá.xhtml and `href="abcá.xhtml"`): Calibre opens the epub with no problem.
- File name contains a string which happens to be URL-decodeable and the same string is written into the content.opf (abc%C3%A1.xhtml and `href="abc%C3%A1.xhtml"`): *Calibre can not open the epub and displays an error message.*

So I guess that Calibre *URL-decodes every path in the content.opf* before it tries to open the files, which can lead to weird edge cases like the last one.
However this seems to be quite a rare case, so I think I am going to process the paths the same way by URL-decoding them.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's probably a bad thing done by InDesign. Two relevant passages from the [OPF spec](http://idpf.org/epub/20/spec/OPF_2.0.1_draft.htm):

From section **1.3.4: Relationship to Unicode**

> Reading Systems must parse all UTF-8 and UTF-16 characters properly (as required by XML). Reading Systems may decline to display some characters, but must be capable of signaling in some fashion that undisplayable characters are present. Reading Systems must not display Unicode characters merely as if they were 8-bit characters.

And section **1.4 Conformance**

> 1.4.1.1: Package Conformance
>
> Each conformant OPF Package Document must meet these necessary conditions:
>
> - it is a well-formed XML document (as defined in XML 1.0); and
> - it is encoded in UTF-8 or UTF-16; and
> - ...

My reading of that is the reading system needs to be capable of parsing `href="abcá.xhtml"`, and so that's what InDesign should put in the .opf file.

Comment: I'm guessing—without testing—that url encodings have variable support with different readers.

Comment: Thanks for the precise info, I tested the behaviour of the Calibre e-book viewer and updated my question with the results.